# how to find 3 immediate words after keyword match using python

Tags: python

I need to extract the director's name after the phrase "directed by" in the following string: " This movie is directed by Francis Ford Coppola. It is a great movie"
I have

```
s = "This movie is directed by Francis Ford 
Coppola. It is a great movie"
match = re.search("^directed by: (\w+){3}",s)
print (match.group(1))
```

But I keep getting : `"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`
What is wrong?

Comment: Remove `^`. It matches the beginning of string.

Comment: Did you want the full name or just the given name? e.g. `re.search(" directed by (\w+){3}",s).group(0).split()[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you need to remove the `:` and the `^` from the pattern. Additionally, the pattern needs to be updated to include a space.

This version creates three match groups, one for each word:

```
>>> s = "This movie is directed by Francis Ford Coppola. It is a great movie"
>>> match = re.search("directed by (\w+) (\w+) (\w+)",s)
>>> match.group(1)
'Francis'
>>> match.group(2)
'Ford'
>>> match.group(3)
'Coppola'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `:`. This character does not exist on your string `s`!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
r = re.search(r'(?<=directed by)((\s+\w+){3})', txt)
print(r.group().strip())
```

Print outputs:

```
>>> 'Francis Ford Coppola'
```